# Android ==> disable multi tasking?

Tags: android, multitasking

1- How can i disable multi tasking?
My application is a  socket based game, every time i start the app, it MUST load the main page first to start the socket connection?
I do not want the user to be able to run my application in background.
Is this possible to do?

2- I do not want the user to be able to use the back button, to navigate between pages, users must only use the buttons available in my application to navigate? is this possible?

Comment: This just smacks of poor design. You need to support the hardware buttons, and you need to recover gracefully from being pushed into the background. AFAIK, these are fundamental design philosophies of Android...

Comment: that's not true. You do not want to keep a socket connected all the time, that kills the battery. And it's not good for a client/server app to keep the connection when user is inactive, that is just waste of bandwidth, and slows the server down

Comment: 1. what the hell? 
2. If your app doesn't run as a service. The socket won't be alive in background. You should read about the lifecycle of an android app. Only service will keep working in the background, all other apps are in "sleep" mode. Unless I read it wrong.
3. You prevent someone from looking in his browser and going back to the game, or receiving a call and going back to the game...

4. You should try to handle reconnection/test if socket is alive. If you run it as a service, add an "idle timeout" and reconnect on request.

Comment: I don't want to allow them to do any of that, the app is a multi-player game where 10 players play against each other, if i allow the user to run the app in the background it'll slow down the game. How is that so hard to understand, when you have a multiplayer game which is turn based, you do not want the users to keep the app running unless they are actually playing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the back button (and ignore it), but you cannot block the Home button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{       
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

Remember, the Phone is just another application so this OS design prevents a rogue application from disabling the "phone" aspect of the device.

If you want to prevent your application from running in the background, you can close the activity from within the onPause() method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

This will force your application to start from scratch if it is put into the background for any reason.  This will probably be called when the phone is put to sleep, however, so it might not be the exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot, great answer.
1 Question: where do i write the second code u provided? In every activity?

Comment: The onPause() code would need to go in any activity that you don't want to allow running in the background.  As Chinmay Kanchi commented though, you are bucking against the Android philosophy so it will be very difficult to design your app this way.  Here is a more detailed explanation of what lifecycle functions are called when: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife

Comment: 1 more thing :), i have a service (socket) running in the background. Does calling finish() kill the service as well?

Comment: Services are killed by the call stopSelf().  If you started the service by calling startService() it should destroy itself automatically when the activity that started it is destroyed.  If you used bindService() you'll have to destroy it manually using stopSelf() to ensure that it is closed.

Comment: You have that backwards. If you use startService(), you have to kill it manually. If you start it by binding to it, it will go away when nothing else is bound to it